# flink InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile$1 is not implementing InputStreamStatistics

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi, apache-flink

I was trying to load an excel into POI workbook in a Flink program. Has an error like this.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile$1 is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile.getInputStream(ZipSecureFile.java:147)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile.getInputStream(ZipSecureFile.java:34)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getInputStream(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:66)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:258)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:725)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:181)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:323)

notice a test https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/f509d1deae86866ed531f10f2eba7db17e098473/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/util/TestZipSecureFile.java here that mention this. But how to work around it. Thanks!

Comment: Check your classpath - my guess is you have an old version of Commons Compress, one that's too old to work with Apache POI

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a newer version of commons-compress and shade it (there ar different plugins in Maven, Gradle, SBT). Alternatively, you can use the HadoopOffice library, which has native Flink support, to read/write Excel files (https://github.com/zuinnote/hadoopoffice/wiki) and it has an example on how to shade the dependency correctly (see https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki/Using-Apache-Flink-to-read-write-Excel-documents)