# xlsx file process with apache poi gives exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using apache poi for read a excel file and process it.

This is what I am doing high level

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_10.xlsx");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();  
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```

But I am getting below exception when create is invoke

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.<init>(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
```

This is only happen with xlsx files. Below is what is create method looks like in poi jar

```
public static Workbook create(InputStream inp, String password) throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException {
        InputStream is = FileMagic.prepareToCheckMagic(inp);
        FileMagic fm = FileMagic.valueOf(is);

        switch (fm) {
            case OLE2:
                POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
                return create(fs, password);
            case OOXML:
                return createXSSFWorkbook(is);
            default:
                throw new IOException("Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream");
        }
    }
```

In xlsx it goes to createXSSFWorkbook

But same scenario I tested with a sample java project and it is working. This exception only comes with the other project which is spring boot project with undertow. Dependency of both projects like poi and commons.compress are same. I can not figure why its gives this exception in that project only

Comment: Could you check that you have commons-compress 1.18 on your classpath? See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62571 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467360/flink-inputstream-of-class-class-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers-zip-zipfi

Comment: Latest jar of commons-compress 1.18 is used. It showed in mvn dependency:tree command

Comment: and there is no possibility that you could have another older copy of commons-compress on your classpath?

Comment: Actually when I check STS build path it showed too under libraries. I even try update maven dependency in STS and ran mvn eclipse:eclipse command too. I later ran the war file from outside STS and the error did not come. After that I switch to different branch and come back and ran from STS, that works too. Not sure what really happen there.